# Что такое кавардак?

Tags: этимология

Кавардак - это синоним беспорядка, хаоса. А что это, вообще, за слово? Что оно означало изначально?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кавардак имеет "вкусное" происхождение. Его современное значение (беспорядок, неразбериха)является переносным, с таким же смыслом мы употребляем такие кулинарные слова, как  каша, винегрет. Слово заимствовано из тюркских языков: кавурдак (тур.)- жаркое, также куурдак (кирг.) - мелко искрошенная и зажаренная в масле баранина.

В русском языке слово "кавардак" сначала также употреблялось как род кушанья, например каварда (волжск.) -  пшенная каша с рыбой. У Жуковского Карп-богатырь ел кавардак по субботам.

Переходным значением для слова стал "кавардак в животе", то есть расстройство пищеварения от неподходящей для русского желудка пищи. Только потом слово стало обозначать беспорядок в общем смысле.